# How can I get (i18next) to work with redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux, i18next, react-i18next

I am very confused by the documentation for i18next and react-18next.

I am using redux to get the translations, but this does not seem to work.

```
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n} initialI18nStore={this.props.translations}>
        <HomeScreen/>
    </I18nextProvider>
```

The initial store is considered 'undefined', which is correct if you are looking at the start of the app (there are obviously no translations). Only after a asynch call do **this.props.tranlsations** become populated, however the i18nStore is still considered empty.

Does this I18nextProvider initialise only once?

Is there a updateStore(), addToStore() method?